# Smarter Way to Initialize Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I made this code to check out how "random" the random function is.

```
Array.prototype.random = function() {
  var index = Math.floor(this.length*Math.random());
  return this[index];
}
var arr = new Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

var count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; //I want to ask about this part

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var val = arr.random();
  console.log(val);

  switch (val) {
    case 'a':
      count[0]++;
      break;
    case 'b':
      count[1]++;
      break;
    case 'c':
      count[2]++;
      break;
    case 'd':
      count[3]++;
      break;
    case 'e':
      count[4]++;
      break;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) console.log(count[i]);
```

In the process, I couldn't think of better way to initialize the 'count' array. Using that way, it would get really repetitive. I would have to put thousand 0 if my 'arr' has 1000 elements. Can anybody suggest better way for me?

If I don't initialize each element of 'count' array as 0, I get NaN.

Comment: `.fill()` method?

Comment: Thanks! I tried! I just had to declare 'count' array differently.

    var count = new Array(arr.length);
    count.fill(0, 0);

but it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Array#fill()` method. For example, to create an array of size 12 entirely filled up with `10`s, you can use the following:

```js
const array = new Array(12).fill(10)
console.log(array)
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)'s some more documentation on this method.

Comment: Thank you!! It really helped

Comment: You're welcome :) If you want, accept the answer so others who come across your question can find it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if that's what you're asking about, but if you want to initialize an array with 1000 same entries, all you need to do is:

```
var count = new Array(1000).fill(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
var temp = new Array(1000);
var count = temp.fill(0);
```

Comment: Thank you too :))))

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to loop over the arguments passed into the function you can access them with the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) keyword.

Comment: I didn't pass any arguments this time, but I'll try using it next time. :)